# win_flex.exe: fatal internal error, fopen(headerfilename) failed

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I downloaded the latest win_flex from sourceforge.
I am getting the following error while running it:

> win_flex.exe: fatal internal error, fopen(headerfilename) failed

using the following command line:

`windows_cmd> win_flex.exe -ogrammer.cpp hello.l`

I am using 64 bit Windows.

Can anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a UAC permissions issue?  I tried to repro doing the following:

1. Downloaded win_flex from http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/?source=dlp
2. Unzipped it in my C:\Users\me\Downloads folder
3. Ran win_flex.exe -ogrammar.cpp hello.l with a trivial .l file:

   %{

   %}

   %%

   %%

Following these steps, I was unable to repro.  You may want to try the same as a sanity check.

If that doesn't work, then open a "cmd" terminal by opening the start menu, typing "cmd", then right-clicking on it and clicking "Run as Administrator..." in the context menu.

I was able to reproduce a similar issue by setting the permissions on the folder that it unzipped to (win-flex-bison_latest) to read-only for everybody and got the following error:

```
win_flex.exe: fseek for temp out failed
```

Also, make sure hello.l is in the same directory as win_flex.exe.

Comment: Hey thanks for your effort!!. Inspite of bounty no one replied except you!. I was able to run it with simple file, but for some complex grammer files, it is giving me the error. Can it be something wrong with my lexer file?

Comment: If it works with a simple file, then you can probably rule out UAC/permissions and the like.  You may just want to start "binary searching" for the part of the .y file that is causing the issue.  Start commenting out half of the file (maintaining correct syntax, of course), until you narrow down which line is the offending line.  You can also try running with the -v switch to get more info.

Comment: Thanks for your effort man!..I am new lex...so I will have to study it....its a very big file around 3k lines...anyws I will surely give it a try...I know 100 points doesn't matter you.. But you get it! Thanks! Keep Helping!